# RevMob implementation errors

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ads, revmob

I'm getting these errors when trying to implement RevMob banner and full screen ads into my app. What can I do?

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[BCFAdsReachability connectionRequired] in RevMobAds(BCFAdsReachability.o)
      -[BCFAdsReachability currentReachabilityStatus] in RevMobAds(BCFAdsReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[BCFAdsReachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in RevMobAds(BCFAdsReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[BCFAdsReachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in RevMobAds(BCFAdsReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[BCFAdsReachability startNotifier] in RevMobAds(BCFAdsReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[BCFAdsReachability stopNotifier] in RevMobAds(BCFAdsReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[BCFAdsReachability startNotifier] in RevMobAds(BCFAdsReachability.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Do some research on the "Undefined symbols for architecture" error message. Learn how to solve them by looking up the symbols.

Answer (score 3):

You must to include the SystemConfiguration framework as described on the [SDK page](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html#configuration).